# Run coroutine inside @Scheduled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I want to run a periodic task. In Spring MVC it works flawlessly.
Now I want to integrate Spring Webflux + Kotlin Coroutines.
How can I call suspended functions in the `@Scheduled` method? I want it to wait until the suspended function is finished.

```kotlin
/// This function starts every 00:10 UTC
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 0 * * *", zone = "UTC")
fun myScheduler() {
    // ???
}

suspend fun mySuspendedFunction() {
    // business logic
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fun myScheduler() {
    runBlocking {
        mySuspendedFunction()
    }
}
```

This way coroutines will run in the thread that was blocked. If you need to run the code in a different thread or execute several coroutines in parallel, you can pass a dispatcher (e.g. `Dispatchers.Default`, `Dispatchers.IO`) to `runBlocking()` or use `withContenxt()`.